# Appium: KeepAliveFailure on Android

Tags: automation, automated-tests, appium, ui-automation, appium-android

Here is my problem: https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/10704

They closed it, but I can't really find a solution for this. Been fighting with this for a bout 2 days.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Android Appium KeepAliveFailure occurs for me when device gets reset or restarted or system app crashes.

Suggestion is take logcat logs and see what went wrong during the error. Analyse the RAM usage in the device.

Comment: May i know which version of selenium webdriver you are using? is it 3.11.2 @Son-nguyen